# Lua Script:attempt to call global 'tonubmer' (a nil value)

Tags: lua, null

I am new to lua,i just don't know why,does it related to environment or the libarary?it drive me crazy, i being search the answer for hours.

```
function gradient()
   local maxStep = 10;
   local starColor="41B0F7";
   local endColor ="1622DF";
   local sb = tonubmer(string.sub(starColor,1,2),16);
   return sb;
end
print(gradient());
```

Comment: Typo: `tonubmer` should be `tonumber`

Comment: Yu Hao solved your mystery, I just wanted to add that you don't need any of the semi-colons.

Comment: Godness,sutpid mistake....3q very much.Y(^_^)Y

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two things going on here:

1. Lua standard library functions like tonumber are global variables.
2. If you try to access a global variable that does not exist (in this case, tonu**bm**er) you get `nil` ny default.

I recommend using a linting tool like [LuaInspect](http://lua-users.org/wiki/LuaInspect) to detect these typos before they bite you.